# Java: Comparación de Strings no se cumple

Tags: java, condiciones

Estoy tratando de imprimir datos generados según una condición que se produce con base en los datos ingresados.

Se supone que debe entrar en las comparaciones `if - else if`, sin embargo, no importa que se cumplan las condiciones nunca entran.

El siguiente código es el que me presenta el problema:

```java
public String listarTrabajador(){
    int i = 1;        
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Trabajadores trab : listaTrabajadores){
        sb.append("Detalle de Trabajadores ").append(i).append("\n");
        sb.append("<------------------------------->").append(i).append("\n");
        sb.append("RUT: ").append(trab.getRut()).append("\n");
        sb.append("NOMBRE: ").append(trab.getNombre()).append("\n");
        sb.append("SEXO: ").append(trab.getSexo()).append("\n");
        sb.append("SUELDO BASE: ").append(trab.getSueldoBase()).append("\n");
        sb.append("EDAD: ").append(trab.getEdad()).append("\n");
        sb.append("CANTIDAD DE HIJOS: ").append(trab.getCantidadDeHijos()).append("\n");           
        
        if(trab.getSexo() == "M" && trab.getEdad() > 45 && trab.getCantidadDeHijos() == 0){
            System.out.println("INCENTIVO: "+trab.getSueldoBase()*0.1);
        }else if(trab.getSexo() == "M" && trab.getEdad() > 45 && trab.getCantidadDeHijos() > 0){
            System.out.println("INCENTIVO: "+trab.getSueldoBase()*0.18);
        }else if(trab.getSexo() == "F" && trab.getEdad() > 40 && trab.getCantidadDeHijos() == 0){
            System.out.println("INCENTIVO: "+trab.getSueldoBase()*0.1);
        }else if(trab.getSexo() == "F" && trab.getEdad() > 40 && trab.getCantidadDeHijos() > 0 && trab.getCantidadDeHijos() <= 3){
            System.out.println("INCENTIVO: "+trab.getSueldoBase()*0.2);
        }else if(trab.getSexo() == "F" && trab.getCantidadDeHijos() > 3){
            System.out.println("INCENTIVO: "+trab.getSueldoBase()*0.25);
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO CUMPLE CONDICIONES PARA RECIBIR INCENTIVO");
        }
}
```

¿Me podrían dar alguna orientación al respecto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las letras entre comillas dobles hacen referencia a un String, por lo cual deberías de hacer la comparación como `"M".equals(...)` o `"M".equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez gracias por responder. "M" es efectivamente un string, que se guarda M o F. El tema es que las condiciones que puse en la publicacion no surten efecto.

Comment: Me refiero a que cambies tus condiciones `trab.getSexo() == "M"` por `"M".equals(trab.getSexo())`

Comment: @EduardoJiménez entendi mal tu comentario. Efectivamente hice los cambios y funciona. Era eso. No entiendo mucho Java y me gustaria si me pudieses dar una breve explicacion del porque se hace asi para entender mas en contexto esta situacion. Agradezo mucho la ayuda brindada. Saludos

Comment: Me tardé un poco porque quise explicarlo lo mejor posible para que no te quedaras con dudas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada quisiera agradecer y decir que esta respuesta se apoya en [las respuestas de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) y en investigación propia.

En contestación a la petición del OP de explicar porqué se debe de usar equals en vez del operador == escribo la siguiente respuesta

## Conceptos previos

**Referencia a un objeto**: Los objetos al crearse son almacenados en memoria heap; para acceder a ellos necesitamos la referencia a ese objeto, pues contiene su ubicación en memoria. Para más información puedes leer: [Understanding Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html) y [How is a Java reference different from a C pointer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer)

**Datos primitivos vs Wrappers**:

> Las implementaciones de wrapper delegan todo su trabajo real a una colección especificada, pero agregan funcionalidad adicional además de lo que ofrece esta colección.

Existen Wrappers de datos primitivos como **Integer e int** o **Character y char**. La diferencia sustancial es que mientras Integer es una clase, int sólo es un dato. Puedes leer un poco más [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-an-integer-and-int-in-java)

## ¿Por qué debo usar `equals` en vez de `==`?

El comparador `==` sirve para:

- Comparar [datos primitivos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- Comparar ubicaciones de memoria de los objetos
- Compararar Strings **únicamente** cuando [intern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()) ha sido invocado para esos Strings. Esto es dado a que *intern* indica que se debe usar [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) sobre `==`

```java
String a = new String("A");

System.out.println("A" == a); // false      
System.out.println(new String("A") == a); // false
System.out.println(new String("A") == "A"); // false
System.out.println(new String("A") == new String("A")); // false
```

Pero quiero que observes qué pasa si cambiamos la inicialización de a:

```java
String a = "A";
System.out.println("A" == a); // true
```

Esto es porque al asignar `a = "A"`, `"A"` se mantiene como una variable internalizada por el compilador. Pongamos otro ejemplo:

```java
String o = new String("a");
String p = o.intern();
String q = "a";

System.out.println(o == p); //false

System.out.println(p == q); //true
System.out.println(q == "a"); //true
System.out.println(p == "a"); //true
```

Para evitar problemas al comparar objetos lo mejor es usar el método sobreescrito de [Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), o mejor aún [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))

```java
String o = new String("a");
String p = new String("a");

// Todos devuelven true
System.out.println(p.equals(o));
System.out.println(o.equals(o));
System.out.println(p.equals("a"));
System.out.println(Objects.equals(o, p));
```

**¿Por qué usar `Objects.equals` o las "Yoda Expresions"?**

La mayoría de las veces nosotros no podemos controlar que un dato no sea null, por ejemplo cuando usamos un parámetro/argumento de un método o al leer un los datos de un archivo.

En esos casos no se puede asegurar que el parámetro no sea nulo sin hacer uso de anotaciones u otros métodos como [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)). Por lo que `null.equals()` sería un error.

Para ello usamos mejor el método `Objects.equals`, o también se usan las "Yoda expressions", es decir, de algo que sabemos que es válido usamos el método.

```java
String o = new String("a");
String p = null;

System.out.println(Objects.equals(o, p));
System.out.println(Objects.equals(p, "a"));

// System.out.println(p.equals("a")); // -> Te arrojaría un error
// Si le aplicamos la Yoda expression a la línea anterior, se evita el error
System.out.println("a".equals(p));
```

**¿Se puede internalizar todo?**

Sí se puede, sin embargo, hay que considerar que en versiones anteriores al JDK7 se usaba un área de memoria conocida como *Permanent Generation*, que es un área de memoria limitada y más pequeña que el Heap por lo que debería usarse con cuidado.

Además de esto tendrías que investigar si hay más problemas de internalizar en las versiones actuales de java. Por el momento, yo no lo recomendaría si no tienes claro que hacer la internalización en tu trabajo traería más beneficios.

## Clases Wrapper de datos primitivos

El mismo problema se presenta en estas clases wrapper, solamente que con una pequeña diferencia, pues estos cuentan con el [AutoBoxing y Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

```java
String o = new String("a");
Integer p = new Integer(5);

System.out.println(o == new String("a")); //false
System.out.println(p == new Integer(5)); //false

System.out.println(o == "a"); //false
System.out.println(p == 5); //true
```

Comment: estimado, muchas gracias de verdad por la explicacion. me queda clarisimo y agradezco el tiempo dedicado en aclarar todo. saludos y muchas gracias nuevamente.