# string obtenido xml salta mi IF

Tags: java, string, condiciones

Hola estoy obteniendo el string de un XML

```
String tipo = e.getElementsByTagName("sdnType").item(0).getTextContent();
String caso= tipo.trim().toLowerCase();
```

pero al pasarlo al condicional aunque me de entity lo salta y no detecta el caso  como entity aunque al imprimir la variable si aparece como entity

```
    if (caso=="entity") {
                            
                            System.out.println("caso entidad");
}
```

lo ignora aunque reviso el string con un

```
System.out.println(caso)
```

me da como salida **entity**

mi codigo completo

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listaentidades.getLength(); i++) {

                Node nodo = listaentidades.item(i);

                if (nodo.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element e = (Element) nodo;
                    NodeList hijos = e.getChildNodes();
                    String tipo = e.getElementsByTagName("sdnType").item(0).getTextContent();
                    
                    String caso= tipo.trim().toLowerCase();
                    System.out.println(caso);
                    


                    if (caso=="entity") {
                        
                        System.out.println("caso entidad");

                        

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("no");


                    }

                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                }
```

lo que me arroja
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para String usa equals() `if (caso.equals("entity"))` [referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495615/java-comparaci%c3%b3n-de-strings-no-se-cumple/495652#495652)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java: Comparación de Strings no se cumple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495615/java-comparaci%c3%b3n-de-strings-no-se-cumple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que pasa es que el operador `==` compara los objetos, los datos primitivos como int, char, float funcionan mejor con este operador, pero `String` es una instancia de clase string, es un objeto, por lo tanto no compara de la misma manera su contenido y no los detecta como del mismo tipo y lo salta.

En este caso si quieres comparar el contenido de **caso** con la cadena `"entity"` se debería usar `.equals()` de esta manera:

```
if (caso.equals("entity")) {
             
                    System.out.println("caso entidad");
```