# PROGRAMA BASICO DE CONTRASEÑAS EN JAVA

Tags: java

HELP

Estas son las instrucciones del programa:

Escribir un programa donde se solicite al usuario 5 veces una contraseña y diga cuantas veces coincidio con una contraseña ya guardada.

```
    package javaapplication27;
    
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class JavaApplication27 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            try {
                System.out.println("Bienvenido al programa de contraseñas.");
                
                System.out.println("Crea aqui tu contraseña nueva: ");
                String contraseña = scanner.nextLine();
                
                String contraseñasIntentos;
                int numero = 0;
                
               for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Ingresa tu contraseña: ");
                    contraseñasIntentos = scanner.nextLine();
                    
                    if (contraseñasIntentos == contraseña) {
                        numero += 1;
                    }
                }
                
                if (numero >= 1) {
                    System.out.println("Ingresaste la contraseña correcta " + numero + " vez/veces.");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Ninguna es la contraseña correcta.");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Hubo un error.");
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("Adios.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Al correr el programa siempre sale el mensaje de "Ninguna es la contraseña correcta."

HELP CON MI TAREA

Comment: No se pueden comparar Strings con dos iguales. En Java la comparación `==` compara OBJETOS, y los compara mirando sus referencias en memoria... si están alojados en diferente espacio del disco, son diferentes objetos. Si ambas referencias apuntan al mismo sitio, son el mismo objeto. Esto es una comparación muy rápida y fácil, pero si creas dos objetos String `"hola"` e intentas compararlos, aunque ambos pongan `"hola"` no son el mismo objeto. Para comparar String se ha de usar el método `equals` de la clase String -> `contraseñasIntentos.equals(contraseña)`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java: Comparación de Strings no se cumple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495615/java-comparaci%c3%b3n-de-strings-no-se-cumple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package javaapplication27;

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication27 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Bienvenido al programa de contraseñas.");
            
            System.out.println("Crea aqui tu contraseña nueva: ");
            String contraseña = scanner.nextLine();
            
            String contraseñasIntentos;
            int numero = 0;
            
           for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu contraseña: ");
                contraseñasIntentos = scanner.nextLine();
                
                if (contraseñasIntentos.equals(contraseña))  {
                    numero += 1;
                }
            }
            
            if (numero >= 1) {
                System.out.println("Ingresaste la contraseña correcta " + numero + " vez/veces.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Ninguna es la contraseña correcta.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Hubo un error.");
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Adios.");
        }
    }
}
```

Un if no puede leer un String, o pones lo que he puesto yo de contraseñasIntentos.equals(contraseña) o lo haces con un switch